# Есть ли у гугл api для получения количества результатов?

Tags: api, search

Я составляю список данных, и мне нужно понимать насколько данные популярны, есть идея использовать для этого google и количество результатов:
[image: Google results]

Желательно, конечно, было бы bulk запросом, вроде посылать сразу:

```
[0] city moscow
[1] city petersburg
...
[99] city new york
```

Результат:

```
(283000000,293000000,..., 7100000000)
```

Comment: Эту строчку можно вытащить из `<div id="resultStats">`, например css-selector = `#resultStats` или xpath-запросом = `//div[@id="resultStats"]`, пример: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/c788e6f50466c59f4bf09917f59b117bfdee6350/search_on_google/search_on_google.py#L21

Comment: Я находил подобное, просто может есть что-то удобнее.

Comment: google не подходит, можно максимум 1000 запросов делать, дальше блокирует

Comment: Нагуглил такое api: https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview

Comment: Да, я тоже находил, но платное, мне по сути главное просто оценивать популярность запроса, у меня таких строк может быть более миллиона. Самое нормальное, что я находил https://rapidapi.com/contextualwebsearch/api/web-search?endpoint=5b864324e4b09cbc25b0013a, но там ограничение для бесплатного пользования 10000/month

Comment: Тогда, используйте например прокси можно и тор попробовать